# How to know what size image to use for background?

Tags: images

I am creating my first Wordpress site using the Sydney theme. I need to replace the background image with a different one specific to my website's purpose. I see where I can switch out the image under Appearance customization, but how can I know what the dimensions need to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer : Any

Detailed Answer : The Sydney theme for WordPress is a very unique and responsive theme. When you upload an image for background then it will automatically be adjusted. But if you really want to add a image of specific dimensions, then 2560*1600 size is best.